# Connection refused when running multiple NettyServer with play 2.5

Tags: scala, netty, playframework-2.5

I'm currently migrating from play 2.4 to 2.5.

I'm trying to run many NettyServer in a test but I can only access the last created

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import org.scalatest.time.{Seconds, Span}
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Results}
import play.core.server.{NettyServer, ServerConfig}
import play.api.routing.sird._

class NettyServerTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures {

  override implicit val patienceConfig = PatienceConfig(Span(5, Seconds))

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val wsClient = AhcWSClient()

  it should "print 'Hello I am the secondServer' then 'Hello I am the firstServer'" in {

    val firstServer = createServer("firstServer")
    val secondServer = createServer("secondServer")
    try {
      println(wsClient.url(s"http://localhost:${secondServer.httpPort.get}/hello").get().futureValue.body)
      println(wsClient.url(s"http://localhost:${firstServer.httpPort.get}/hello").get().futureValue.body)
    } finally {
      firstServer.stop()
      secondServer.stop()
    }
  }

  def createServer(server: String): NettyServer = {
    NettyServer.fromRouter(ServerConfig(port = Some(0))) {
      case GET(p"/hello") => Action {
        Results.Ok(s"Hello I am the $server")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the test it only prints 'Hello I am the secondServer' then I get the error:

```
The future returned an exception of type: java.net.ConnectException, with message: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58096.
ScalaTestFailureLocation: NettyServerTest$$anonfun$1 at (NettyServerTest.scala:28)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: The future returned an exception of type: java.net.ConnectException, with message: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58096.
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Futures$FutureConcept$class.tryTryAgain$1(Futures.scala:531)
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Futures$FutureConcept$class.futureValue(Futures.scala:558)
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures$$anon$1.futureValue(ScalaFutures.scala:74)
    at NettyServerTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(NettyServerTest.scala:28)
    at NettyServerTest$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServerTest.scala:22)
...
```

I have the following dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-netty-server" % "2.5.4"
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.5.4"
```

This test was working with play 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I succeed to make it work by overriding the actorSystem used by the netty server:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import org.scalatest.time.{Seconds, Span}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import play.api.BuiltInComponents
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Results}
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.core.server.{NettyServer, NettyServerComponents, ServerConfig}

class NettyServerTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures {

  override implicit val patienceConfig = PatienceConfig(Span(5, Seconds))

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val wsClient = AhcWSClient()

  it should "print 'Hello I am the secondServer' then 'Hello I am the firstServer'" in {

    val firstServer = createServer("firstServer")
    val secondServer = createServer("secondServer")
    try {
      wsClient.url(s"http://localhost:${firstServer.httpPort.get}/hello").get().futureValue.body shouldBe "Hello I am the firstServer"
      wsClient.url(s"http://localhost:${secondServer.httpPort.get}/hello").get().futureValue.body shouldBe "Hello I am the secondServer"
    } finally {
      firstServer.stop()
      secondServer.stop()
    }
  }

  def createServer(serverName: String): NettyServer = {
    new NettyServerComponents with BuiltInComponents {
      lazy val router = Router.from {
        case GET(p"/hello") => Action {
          Results.Ok(s"Hello I am the $serverName")
        }
      }
      override lazy val serverConfig = ServerConfig(port = Some(0))
      override lazy val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
    }.server
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I was creating multiple servers to mock out external services, and this proved very useful. But now thinking about it; it's probably better to create one server and just change the routes/partial functions together.